Show $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, \text{Li}_n\left( e^{-t} \right) \, dt = \sum_{k=2}^{n} (-1)^{n-k} \zeta(k) + (-1)^{n+1}$
Define the integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, \text{Li}_n\left( e^{-t} \right) \, dt \tag{1}
$$
where the Polylogarithm function
$$\text{Li}_n(e^{-t}) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-kt}}{k^n}$$
Notice that WolframAlpha shows this pattern for $(1)$
\begin{array}{c|l}
n & \text{Result} \\
\hline
2 & \zeta(2) - 1 \\
3 & \zeta(3) - \zeta(2) + 1 \\
4 & \zeta(4) - \zeta(3) + \zeta(2) - 1 \\
5 & \zeta(5) - \zeta(4) + \zeta(3) - \zeta(2) + 1 \\
6 & \zeta(6) - \zeta(5) + \zeta(4) - \zeta(3) + \zeta(2) - 1 \\
7 & \zeta(7) - \zeta(6) + \zeta(5) - \zeta(4) + \zeta(3) - \zeta(2) + 1 \\
... & ...\\
n & \sum_{k=2}^{n} (-1)^{n-k} \zeta(k) + (-1)^{n+1} \\
\end{array}
Interestingly, $(1)$ can be represented by the Laplace transform
$$
\mathcal{L}\{ f(t) \}(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-s t} f(t) \, dt
$$
where $f(t) = \text{Li}_n(e^{-t})$ and $s=1$.
Claim
For $n \ge 2$,
$$
\boxed{ \mathcal{L}\{\text{Li}_n(e^{-t})\}(1) = \sum_{k=2}^{n} (-1)^{n-k} \zeta(k) + (-1)^{n+1}}
$$
Proof
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}\{\text{Li}_n(e^{-t})\}(1)
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, \text{Li}_n(e^{-t}) \, dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \left( \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-kt}}{k^n} \right) dt \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^n} \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(k+1)t} \, dt \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^n} \cdot \frac{1}{(k+1)}
\end{align*}
To complete the proof, how to solve this series (or reference)?
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^n (k+1)}
$$

This appears related to this thread (see the comments)

Thanks. $$ {\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{n}(k+s)}} = {\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{s^{n}}H_{s}} + {\frac{(-1)^{n}}{s^{n+1}}\sum_{k=2}^{n}(-s)^{k}\zeta(k)} $$

The simplest way is:
$$ 
\begin{align} \color{blue}{\frac{1}{k^{n}}} 
=&\,\, \frac{1\color{red}{+k-k}}{k^{n}} =\frac{1+k}{k^{n}}-\frac{1}{k^{n-1}} \\[3mm] 
=&\,\, \frac{1+k}{k^{n}}-\frac{1+k}{k^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{k^{n-2}} \\[3mm] 
=& +(-1)^{0}\frac{1+k}{k^{n}}+(-1)^{1}\frac{1+k}{k^{n-1}}+ \\ 
& \dots+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1+k}{k^{1}}+(-1)^{n}\frac{1}{k^{0}} \\[3mm] 
=&\,\, \color{blue}{(-1)^{n}+(k+1)\sum\limits_{m=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{n-m}}{k^{m}}} \\[3mm] 
=&\,\, \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{k}+(k+1)\sum\limits_{m=\color{red}{2}}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{n-m}}{k^{m}} \\[3mm] 
\Rightarrow\frac{1}{k^{n}(k+1)}=&\,\, \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{k(k+1)}+\sum\limits_{m=2}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{n-m}}{k^{m}} \\[3mm] 
\end{align} 
$$
Hence:
$$ 
\begin{align} \color{red}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{n}(k+1)}} 
&= (-1)^{n-1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}+\sum\limits_{m=2}^{n}(-1)^{n-m}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{m}} \\[3mm] 
&= \color{red}{(-1)^{n+1}+\sum\limits_{m=2}^{n}(-1)^{n-m}\zeta(m)} \\[3mm] 
\end{align} 
$$
Where $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=1$.

Note
$$
I_n:=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, \text{Li}_n\left( e^{-t} \right) \, dt=
-\int_0^\infty \text{Li}_n\left( e^{-t} \right)\;de^{-t}\\
=-e^{-t}\text{Li}_n\left( e^{-t} \right)\bigg|_0^{\infty}-\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t}\text{Li}_{n-1}\left( e^{-t} \right)dt=\text{Li}_n\left(1\right)-I_{n-1}=\zeta_n-I_{n-1}$$
and from this recursion, it is easy to get the desired identity.
